# What is the optimal solution to prove the reachbility of a node from the root?

Tags: graphs, finite-automata, graph-traversal

I have a finite automaton with these properties:

- Contains cycles
- It's a directed graph
- All the states/nodes are initialy reachable from the initial state
- It has final states but I guess it isn't relevant for my issue
- It's a random generated automaton, and the generation isn't meant to satisfy properties like strongly connected components or connected components

Let's suppose I have to delete an edge.

I need to know if there's a way to prove that the reached state by this edge is still reachable from the initial state without using a classical search (DFS or BFS); obviously, if there is any.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a difficult problem. For undirected graphs, this is known as "dynamic connectivity". You can see [slides](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d1/teaching/ss12/AdvancedGraphAlgorithms/Slides08.pdf) describing an $O(\log^2 n)$ algorithm, or the [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.919&rep=rep1&type=pdf) itself. For directed graphs, there is an algorithm no better than DFS described in [this paper](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/research/liam.roditty/papers/roditty.pdf) (the algorithm is better than DFS if you are making several connectivity queries each time). A [paper](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/classes/papers/PatrascuTowards.pdf) by Pătraşcu gives evidence that polylogarithmic update time isn't possible for directed graphs.